# python: input any number and convert to text

Tags: python

Looking to extend this program to take an input of any number, including decimal and output text. 
ie) 45.23 Forty five point twenty three

```
num1 = str(input("enter a dollar amt:"))

numToString = {'1.00':'one dollar', '1.50':'one dollar and fifty cents',\
'2.00':'two dollars', '3.00': 'three dollars', '4.00':'four dollars', \
'5.00':'five dollars', '6.00':'six dollars', '7.00':'seven dollars', \
'8.00':'eight dollars', '9.00':'nine dollars'} ;

for char in num1:
    print(numToString[char])
```

Comment: change dictionary to `{"1": "one", "2": "two", ".": "point"}` because in `for loop` we are iterating `num1` string i.e. one character at one time..

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
import math

# Tokens from 1000 and up
_PRONOUNCE = [
    'vigintillion',
    'novemdecillion',
    'octodecillion',
    'septendecillion',
    'sexdecillion',
    'quindecillion',
    'quattuordecillion',
    'tredecillion',
    'duodecillion',
    'undecillion',
    'decillion',
    'nonillion',
    'octillion',
    'septillion',
    'sextillion',
    'quintillion',
    'quadrillion',
    'trillion',
    'billion',
    'million',
    'thousand',
    ''
]

# Tokens up to 90
_SMALL = {
    '0' : '',
    '1' : 'one',
    '2' : 'two',
    '3' : 'three',
    '4' : 'four',
    '5' : 'five',
    '6' : 'six',
    '7' : 'seven',
    '8' : 'eight',
    '9' : 'nine',
    '10' : 'ten',
    '11' : 'eleven',
    '12' : 'twelve',
    '13' : 'thirteen',
    '14' : 'fourteen',
    '15' : 'fifteen',
    '16' : 'sixteen',
    '17' : 'seventeen',
    '18' : 'eighteen',
    '19' : 'nineteen',
    '20' : 'twenty',
    '30' : 'thirty',
    '40' : 'forty',
    '50' : 'fifty',
    '60' : 'sixty',
    '70' : 'seventy',
    '80' : 'eighty',
    '90' : 'ninety'
}

def get_num(num):
    '''Get token <= 90, return '' if not matched'''
    return _SMALL.get(num, '')

def triplets(l):
    '''Split list to triplets. Pad last one with '' if needed'''
    res = []
    for i in range(int(math.ceil(len(l) / 3.0))):
        sect = l[i * 3 : (i + 1) * 3]
        if len(sect) < 3: # Pad last section
            sect += [''] * (3 - len(sect))
        res.append(sect)
    return res

def norm_num(num):
    """Normelize number (remove 0's prefix). Return number and string"""
    n = int(num)
    return n, str(n)

def small2eng(num):
    '''English representation of a number <= 999'''
    n, num = norm_num(num)
    hundred = ''
    ten = ''
    if len(num) == 3: # Got hundreds
        hundred = get_num(num[0]) + ' hundred'
        num = num[1:]
        n, num = norm_num(num)
    if (n > 20) and (n != (n / 10 * 10)): # Got ones
        tens = get_num(num[0] + '0')
        ones = get_num(num[1])
        ten = tens + ' ' + ones
    else:
        ten = get_num(num)
    if hundred and ten:
        return hundred + ' ' + ten
        #return hundred + ' and ' + ten
    else: # One of the below is empty
        return hundred + ten

def num2eng(num):
    '''English representation of a number'''
    num = str(long(num)) # Convert to string, throw if bad number
    if (len(num) / 3 >= len(_PRONOUNCE)): # Sanity check
        raise ValueError('Number too big')

    if num == '0': # Zero is a special case
        return 'zero '

    # Create reversed list
    x = list(num)
    x.reverse()
    pron = [] # Result accumolator
    ct = len(_PRONOUNCE) - 1 # Current index
    for a, b, c in triplets(x): # Work on triplets
        p = small2eng(c + b + a)
        if p:
            pron.append(p + ' ' + _PRONOUNCE[ct])
        ct -= 1
    # Create result
    pron.reverse()
    return ', '.join(pron)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    numbers = [1.37, 0.07, 123456.00, 987654.33]
    for number in numbers:
        dollars, cents = [int(num) for num in str(number).split(".")]

        dollars = num2eng(dollars)
        if dollars.strip() == "one":
            dollars = dollars + "dollar and "
        else:
            dollars = dollars + "dollars and "

        cents = num2eng(cents) + "cents"
        print dollars + cents
```